# laravel polymorphic relation with custom parent model Foreign key and other where conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Howdy here i'm trying to set a custom foreign key for my one-one polymorphic relations below is my  code

i have AttendanceNotice Model

```
public function reportable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'reporter_type', 'reporter_id');
    }
```

Guardian Model

```php
    public function report()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(AttendanceNotice::class, 'reportable');
    }
```

Employee Model

```php
    public function report()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(AttendanceNotice::class, 'reportable');
    }
```

so when i retrieve attendanceNotice record its using the primary key of each related model which as i expect is the default but what i want to achieve

1. use another column as the foreign key instead of the `id` of each related model
2. add some extra query constraint when retrieving record via `AttendanceNotice::query()`

```php
$res = AttendanceNotice::query()->withoutGlobalScopes()
        ->with('reportable')->get();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a custom foreign key for your polymorphic relation and add additional query constraints, you can modify your models and queries accordingly.

Update your AttendanceNotice model to use a custom foreign key and add other constraints:

```
class AttendanceNotice extends Model
{
    public function reportable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo('reportable', 'reporter_type', 'reporter_id');
    }

    // Add a scope to apply additional constraints
    public function scopeCustomConstraints($query)
    {
        // Add your custom constraints here
        // For example, you can add a where condition
        $query->where('your_column', '=', 'your_value');
    }
}
```

Update your Guardian and Employee models to specify the custom foreign key:

```
class Guardian extends Model
{
    public function report()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(AttendanceNotice::class, 'reportable', 'reporter_type', 'reporter_id');
    }
}

class Employee extends Model
{
    public function report()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(AttendanceNotice::class, 'reportable', 'reporter_type', 'reporter_id');
    }
}
```

When querying the AttendanceNotice model, you can use the custom scope to apply additional constraints:

```
$res = AttendanceNotice::query()
    ->withoutGlobalScopes()
    ->with('reportable')
    ->customConstraints()
    ->get();
```